# Skyrim the Ebony Warrior

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have recently come across the Ebony warrior and was wondering what level he is? And what weapons are the most effective against him. I have died like 6 times now...

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Warrior

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort.

Comment: [The UESP Wiki is a good place to search for Skyrim-related info like this.](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Ebony_Warrior)

Comment: Lack of research is not a good reason to downvote. StackExchange is meant to be an aggregation of knowledge generated in Q&A style. This would be a valid question, were it phrased correctly.

Answer (score 4):

RAW stats from this wiki page: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Warrior

Stats:

```
Level   80
Health  2071
Magicka 250
Stamina 364
```

Resistances:

> he Ebony warrior is 50% resistant to fire, frost, and shock through
>   his enchanted apparel. As a Redguard, he is 50% resistant to poison.
>   He is also immune to the following spells and shouts:
>
> ```
>     Ash Shell
>     Bend Will
>     Dead Thrall
>     Ice Form
>     Paralyze
>     Soul Tear
>     Wabbajack
>     Whirlwind Cloak
>     Vampiric Grip
> ```

[some effective strategies include](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:The_Ebony_Warrior):

- High level alteration magic to reduce the amount of damage he does to you.
- Using the unrelenting force shout to push him off a cliff.
- staggering him with destruction magic (with the appropriate perk)
- using an 'essential' NPC companion as a distraction

Answer (score 2):

[From a quick Google search, this wiki shows that the Ebony Warrior is level 81.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Warrior) [This page seems to discuss some available strategies.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:The_Ebony_Warrior)

It does honestly depend on your playstyle.

For an archer or melee character, be sure to load up on Drain Stamina and Drain Magicka poisons. Without any magic to heal himself or stamina to unload power attacks against you, this should make the fight a lot easier. Stocking up on powerful poisons and potions will turn this fight into easysauce with Invisibility, Slow, epic heals, etc....

Consequently a mage should be able to stagger him indefinitely with the appropriate destruction perk. Unload ice and shock to drain his magic and stamina if you want to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Colin's suggestion to use Unrelenting Force to damage him by knocking him off of the cliff, I suggest meditating on the "Fus" word from Parthuurnax if you have not killed him. This makes your opponents more likely to stagger(25%) by any means, and you less likely to stagger by any means by the same percentage. When I faced him, he healed himself a few times - his bow also paralyzes you, so be wary if you are a ranged attacker.